# CSS How to join lines

Tags: css, line

I have to horizontal lines created with CSS in `<div>` elements, now I want to join them with another line(the one drawn by hand), any ideas? The image of what I'm doing below:

[image]

```css
.canvas {
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}

.top-line {
  top: 100px;
  left: 256px;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  height: 1px;
  width: 488px;
}

.bottom-line {
  top: 900px;
  left: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  height: 1px;
  width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="canvas">
  <div class="top-line"></div>
  <div class="left-line"></div>
  <div class="right-line"></div>
  <div class="bottom-line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you must make the lines 4 different divs? you could add a border to the container and `transform: skew()` it.

Comment: Are you open to solutions that involve Javascript, or are you looking for a pure CSS solution to this?

Comment: use a table cell with a rowspan that is the number of rows between the top line and the bottom line then put a gif there with an image of a line of appropriate height/width

Answer (score 1):

You can consider one element and some transformation to visually achieve what you want:

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid;
  border-right:none; /*remove this if you want the right line too*/
  transform:perspective(30px) rotateX(5deg);
  transform-origin:bottom center;
}

body {
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Another idea considering skew transformation:

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  border-bottom:1px solid;
  position:relative;
}
.box:before,
.box:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
  border-top:1px solid;
}
.box:before {
  border-left:1px solid;
  transform-origin:bottom left;
  left:0;
  transform:skew(-10deg);
}
.box:after {
  /*border-right:1px solid; add this for the right line */
  transform-origin:bottom right;
  right:0;
  transform:skew(10deg);
}

body {
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I write some **CSS** for `left-line` in below code snippet, i hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```
.left-line {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    height: 815px;
    position: relative;
    left: 161px;
    transform: rotate(11deg);
    top: 181px;
}
```

```css
.canvas {
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}

.top-line {
  top: 100px;
  left: 256px;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  height: 1px;
  width: 488px;
}

.bottom-line {
  top: 900px;
  left: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  height: 1px;
  width: 800px;
}

.left-line {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    height: 815px;
    position: relative;
    left: 161px;
    transform: rotate(11deg);
    top: 181px;
}
```

```html
<div class="canvas">
    <div class="top-line"></div>
    <div class="left-line"></div>
    <div class="right-line"></div>
    <div class="bottom-line"></div>
</div>
```